# How can I tell which JSON serialization will be used on my Azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, json-serialization

In Visual Studio, if I create a new project using the "Azure Functions" template, the JSON serialization used by that function will be different depending on which version of the template I use. I'm wondering how can I tell which JSON serialization will be used, solely from looking at the code/project.

**Minimal complete and viable example**

(you need to have the Visual Studio "Azure" workload installed to do this)

1. Create a new project using the "Azure Functions" template, choose ".NET 6.0 (Long term support)" and use the default options for everything else.
2. Replace the `string responseMessage` and `return` lines with this code:

```cs
            var content = new ResponseContent();
            return new OkObjectResult(content);
```

3. Add this class to the project:

```cs
    public class ResponseContent
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("CouldBeThis")]
        public string Example { get; set; } = "MyValue";
    }
```

4. Create a new project using the "Azure Functions" template, choose ".NET 6.0 Isolated (Long Term Support)" and use the default options for everything else.
5. Replace the `return` line with the same code as shown in 2.
6. Add this class to the project:

```cs
    public class ResponseContent
    {
        [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("ButMaybeThis")]
        public string Example { get; set; } = "MyValue";
    }
```

7. Run both projects, and use a browser to visit the URL shown for each project. The outputs are, respectively:

```json
{
    "CouldBeThis": "MyValue"
}
```

and

```json
{
    "ButMaybeThis": "MyValue"
}
```

The above is demonstrating that one project is using `Newtonsoft.Json` for Json serialization, but the other is using `System.Text.Json`. But if I had not yet put any attributes on that object, then how could I have determined which JSON serialization will be used, solely from looking at the code/project?

**EDIT after request to add the complete function code**

Here's the complete in-process function (steps 1-3 above):

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionAppA
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            ResponseContent content = new ResponseContent();
            return new OkObjectResult(content);
        }
    }

    public class ResponseContent
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("CouldBeThis")]
        public string Example { get; set; } = "MyValue";
    }
}
```

and here's the complete isolated version

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionAppI
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            ResponseContent content = new ResponseContent();
            return new OkObjectResult(content);
        }

        public class ResponseContent
        {
            [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("ButMaybeThis")]
            public string Example { get; set; } = "MyValue";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *....depending on which version of the template I use* >>> Are you referring to the Azure functions Version? Also please provide your function code.

Comment: *"Are you referring to the Azure functions Version?"* yes, as mentioned in steps 1 & 4. *"Also please provide your function code."* I will edit the question to add this; but it's basically what is currently in the templates (my versions are all up to date), plus the minor changes shown above.

Comment: Can you provide AzureFunctionsVersion(V3/V4), you can check in .csproj?

Comment: Both are `<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>`

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK in the latest versions, Azure Functions by default uses the venerable `Newtonsoft.Json` package. This package is included as a dependency of the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` package in `.csproj` project file.

Though Azure Functions uses the same `OkObjectResult` class from `ASP.NET Core framework`, the serialization process in Azure Functions is handled differently due to its reliability on `Newtonsoft.Json`.

1. If the function code has `using Newtonsoft.Json` namespace and  `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` , `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` packages in your  project,  it indicates the use of `Newtonsoft.Json`:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

[image]

- The code uses methods like **JsonConvert.SerializeObject()** or **JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()**.

2. If your function code has `using System.Text.Json` namespace, and  `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions` , `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Json` packages in your  `csproj`  file, it indicates the use of `System.Text.Json`.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

- The code uses methods like **JsonSerializer.Serialize()** or **JsonSerializer.Deserialize()**.

**Note: *The function code you have provided is using Newtonsoft.json.***

**References:**

https://svrooij.io/2023/07/26/system-text-json-azure-functions/

Comment: *"AFAIK in the latest versions, Azure Functions by default uses the venerable Newtonsoft.Json package."* I'm sorry, but the question actually demonstrates this answer to not be true because the first template (which uses Newtonsoft) is "in-process" which is older than the "isolated" approach (which uses System.Text.Json). *"The function code you have provided is using Newtonsoft.json."* I'm only doing that to prove what _is_ being used by the implementation. I want to know how I could have known that if I had not put those attributes there.

Comment: For example, the "isolated" example from the question (steps 4-6), once I have removed the attribute does not meet either (1) or (2) from your answer. Please try the MCVE given in the question.

Comment: I will check and update the answer accordingly.